# Change imageview image src on screen orientation change

Tags: java, android

I'm making a simple android app that loads a webpage in a webview and there is a splash screen as a loading screen in an imageview that appears at start with url loading.
My problem is that I want to load different images according to the screen orientation
here is my code
activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.example.MainActivity">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageLoading1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:src="@mipmap/vert_loading" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.example.com/");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                //hide loading image
                findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //show webview
                findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

I have another image for the landscape layout in the same folder but how to load it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create different layout folders for each orientation.

- `layout-port` for portrait mode.
- `layout-land`for landscape mode.

Or, if you want to change only the `image src` you can detect the orientation changed event inside your `Activity` and load the new image.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) 
        // Set landscape image src
    else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        // Set portrait image src
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Grender described you can load different layouts for portrait and landscape.
You can also use the programmatically way.

Set the imageview src in your onCreate method and use.

```
int orientation = Activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) 
    // Set landscape image src
else if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
    // Set portrait image src
```

So if you change your screen orientation, the onCreate method is called again and this code decides which src your imageview should use.

Edit:
Thanks to Grender for the hint that in onCreate you should use your activity resources.

Comment: why not? It solves the problem but my hint was not to use the onConfigurationChanged method but onCreate. Don't know what's your problem, I've posted your name.

Comment: But your answer is not correct, if you want to know the orientation outside `onConfigurationChanged()` method you must use `yourActivity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation`. You should check the code before copying from anyone.

Comment: you're totally right sorry :)
I will change that. Certainly in onCreate you don't have "newConfig".